# Column Order of an Interactive Grid based on user Input

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Can column order of an interactive grid be defined such that column order changes based on user input.

For example, if user chooses 'A' as value in Select List, then the column order of the report should be 'A1','A2','A3','B1','B2',B3', and if user chooses 'B' as value in select list, then the column order of the report should be 'B1','B2','B3','A1','A2','A3'.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Your title says "Interactive Grid" but your question says "interactive report". Please identify which you are using as the methods differ.

Comment: Apologies. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a couple of possibilities to do this. Haven't tested any of it, you'll need to do the heavy lifting yourself.

1. Best solution: create 2 saved reports, lookup the id and change them with javascript on a dynamic action when user selects A or B: Check this thread, it has the javascript function: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4173941
2. Easiest solution: create 2 reports, reportA with col order A1, A2, ... and reportB with col order B1, B2, ... and set a dynamic action on user input so when user selects A, then reportA is shown and reportB is hidden and vice versa for when user selects B.

As I said, I have not tested this. I also have no access to a 5.1 installation so you're on your own here.

Comment: Unfortunately, the select list in my application has country names (166 entries), which requires different column order for every country. It would a lot of repetitive code, which it something I was trying not to do.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other solutions than the ones above.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to set column order through JavaScript in Oracle APEX. Anyways, thanks for your effort for trying to find me an answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can!**

If you make any changes to the current Interactive Grid. For example by changing the column order or sorting on a particular column. You can save individual reports through the Interactive Grid Actions menu by clicking Actions > Report > Save / Save as. Clicking `Save` just saves the current report with its changes. Clicking `Save as` presents you with extra options:

[image: Saving a report in the Interactive Grid Actions Menu]

[image: Save as an alternative report: this report is made by a developer so all other authorized users will be able to select this report]
[image: Save as a private report, so only the current user is able to see this report]

Save as an alternative or private report. An alternative report is made by a developer so all other authorized users will be able to select this report. A private report is only available to the user who created it.

Now a report has been saved and is accessible via the Interactive Grid UI and [the interactiveGrid Javascript API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html#actions-section):
[image: Users can easily select all their reports]

```
const igActions = apex.region('static-id-of-interactive-grid').call('getActions');
let choices = igActions.lookup("change-report").choices;

// choices:
// [
//     {
//         "group": "Default",
//         "label": "Primary Report",
//         "value": "15670669007633042906"
//     },
//     {
//         "group": "Default",
//         "label": "Alternative Report",
//         "value": "31341498576910093801"
//     },
//     {
//         "group": "Private",
//         "label": "Private Report",
//         "value": "47018667528607243801"
//     }
// ]

let alternative = choices.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.label === "Alternative Report";
})[0].value;

igActions.set("change-report", alternative);
```

For a more elaborate understanding of reports in an Interactive Grid see [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmdb/saving-interactive-grids-reports.html#GUID-77A38D73-39B7-4FB7-ABF0-9CAE2D297175) from Oracle

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `UNION`, e.g.

```
select a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3
  from your_table
  where :P1_SELECT_LIST = 'A'
union
select b1, b2, b3, a1, a2, a3 
  from your_table
  where :P1_SELECT_LIST = 'B'
```

Note that columns have to match in datatypes.

---

If they don't match, there's another *simple* solution: create the report (grid) "as is", using all columns in any order. Run the page, go to the "Actions" menu and "Columns" to *reorder* columns in any way you want. Then save that report as a *custom* report. Do the same for another layout. Doing so, you'd have two layouts to choose from.

Comment: Unfortunately, datatypes for these columns are different. I was thinking of setting column order by a javascript dynamic action that can fire on submit page button. But unfortunately, I couldn't find any way how to do that.

Comment: How about using the "Actions" button? I described it in the answer. Have a look, please.

Comment: Why not? Works for me.

Comment: I am using Oracle APEX 5.1.4. I think that's why it is not working for me.

Comment: Is there any way I can set column order by JavaScript?

Comment: Huh, I don't have 5.x any more and can't remember how it worked. As of JavaScript, sorry, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks anyways for your effort in finding me an answer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem; I hope someone else will be able to assist.